# How do you set up cURL in php to only get the printable version of a webpage?

Tags: php, html, css, curl

I'm trying to copy the HTML source from someone else's web site using cURL in php. I only want to get the HTML that they designate printable, and not their headers and footers and images.  My intent is to speed up the download, and put less of a burden on their site. They have updated their page for the first time in 8 years and changed to using CSS instead of a GET variable to designate the printable version of the page.  Is it possible to tell cURL to only return the printable elements?
Edit: They are using a lot of statements like this in their CSS:

```
@media print {
    .visible-print-block {
        display: block !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Without parsing the print media stylesheet, I don't think it would be possible because all of the HTML is still there. The print view doesn't remove any HTML nodes, it just hides them according to the CSS.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

probably this is not the answer you expected, but except parsing the DOM tree and rendering the HTML yourself you can not produce the printable version.

However back in 1999, for web based email, we used something like this:

```
system("lynx --dump 'www.microsoft.com'");
```

This works well, but:

- probably works out of the box on `linux`, on `MacOS` and `Windows` you need to install `lynx` browser.
- it is slow - because it `fork` `lynx` browser
- you need to take some care and to encode the domain, probably with `escapeshellarg`.
- `lynx` does not support `Javascript`, nor very advanced `CSS`

Another way is to use some of many software packages for making screenshots. However they will produce images instead of text.